# Slow Loading Time

Tags: html, image, wordpress, caching, load

I have a website where it is taking too long to load, I believe the issue is the images loading in the sidebar. However I have come across another website that has the same feature as this website and that seems to load fast.

I am using wordpress and someone mentioned to me it could be something to do with caching, but I am not too familiar with this.

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can speed up the load time?

Comment: A million things can impact loading speed, from server load to image size. It's impossible to diagnose what your issue is without seeing code or the site itself. If you're interested in WP caching, try WP Super Cache or any of the similar plugins: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/  However that won't speed up image loading.

Comment: Thanks, that plugin seems to have done the job, but what are the disadvantages of using a caching plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to 1st make sure your images are optimized for the web:

You can do it with the smush.it plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/
or in photoshop by saving for web.

Also, consider using image sprites where appropriate - An image sprite is a collection of images put into a single image.

As for slow page loading in Wordpress install these plug-ins:

optimize-db plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/optimize-db/

w3-total-cache plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors to speed up wordpress. JFelton explained it well and you should try them but do try Autoptimize which increases good speed as well. Though if your issue is only images I would suggest getting a good hosting and a good CDN.